# Curl and Browser are serving different versions of file

Tags: apache, file, version, rhel

I have a wsdl(essentially an xml) file on the server. Now when i access this file from the browser I get the latest version however when i use curl or wget to get this file i get a version which is older.

Another interesting thing which happens is that even on deleting the file the curl is still able to get the file but the browser correctly gets a 404.

I am not sure why this is happening when the protocol to get the file in both the cases is http and i see the request coming correctly in the apache access logs. However the file being served in both the cases are different.

I am using apache webserver on a RHEL machine.

Any pointers why this could happen.

Comment: Proxy in CURL? And, maybe User-Agent processing?

Comment: I tried passing User Agent as well via curl but still it is the same.